# warningsAccepted=true header parameter in Python

Tags: python, url, http-headers

I am using an api, where it give some of the api related warning.
To bypass the api warnings, I am trying to use " warningsAccepted=True" in the url header.
I have tried below code.
However, this did not fix my issue. Could you please help me to fix issue.

```
url="https://example.com"
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'bearer %s' %bearer_token, 
        'Content-Type': 'application/ld+json',
        'warning-accepted': True
    }
    
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers)
```

error message:

```
InvalidHeader: Value for header {warningsAccepted: True} must be of type str or bytes, not <class 'bool'>
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Try `'warning-accepted': 'True'`.

```
url="https://example.com"
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'bearer %s' %bearer_token, 
        'Content-Type': 'application/ld+json',
        'warning-accepted': 'True'
    }
    
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers)
```